# Copy UIImage to pasteboard

Tags: swift, keyboard, uipasteboard

I'm making a custom keyboard extension. I want people to be able to send stickers from the keyboard using the pasteboard function. But this code `UIPasteboard.GeneralPasteboard().image = image;` doesn't copy the stickers to the pasteboard? Anyone know the proper code for swift 2.0?

Comment: `UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().image = image` is working for me.  I assume your uppercase `G` was just a typo.

Comment: The typing is correct, how do you verified that the image has indeed been copied to the pasteboard?

Comment: I created two test apps.  The first saves an image into the pasteBoard and the second reads the image from the pasteBoard and displays it in a UIImageView.  Running both apps on the simulator works successfully for me.

Comment: I have accomplished the same result as you have and i can now verify that my image is indeed copied to the pasteboard. But the idea is to insert these stickers into a messages ;) Are you able to copy the sticker and then pasting it into fx. facebook or iMessages?

Comment: What those apps do with images in the pasteBoard is up to them.   I don't know what format the messaging apps need images to be in to insert them.  Perhaps its just a size issue, or perhaps there is another mechanism altogether.

Comment: I will try to research further what format the different messages apps use. Anyway thank you very much for your time and help. I got little closer :d

Comment: UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().image = image i tried it but not working for me. And also tried UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().setValue method.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().setValue(image, forPasteboardType: "public.image")
```

Comment: Hi, I used the  UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().setValue but when I tried that the app getting crashed with the following message.
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPasteboard setValue:forPasteboardType:]: value is not a valid property list type'

Comment: Hi, @Ramakrishna. Check the value type and type string 'public.image/RTF/...' . May be you try set other type.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got the solution by using setData() method.

Answer (score 0):

Provide your custom keyboard full access in the settings. Settings -> General -> Keyboards -> YourKeyBoard -> Allow Full Access

You couldn't copy / paste image to clip board unless you provide full access to the keyboard extension.

Comment: Hi @Ramakrishna if you're using Swift 3, try copying image using the following syntax: `UIPasteboard.general.image = [your UIImage]` In my case, I wasn't able to copy UIImage to UIPasteboard until full access is not given to the custom keyboard in the settings app.

Comment: Hi, I'm not using the swift 3. Using swift 2.2 and I understand that and also set the RequestsOpenAccess to true in .plist file.

Comment: I don't even get copy option when i select the image in my keyboard.

Comment: Ahh, you have to implement 'copy' programmatically. Are you showing images in some UITableView or UICollectionView in your custom keyboard?

Comment: yeah, i'm showing images using the collection view.
Here my code:
    let pb = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard();
    let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "1.png")!;
    let imgData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!;
    pb.setData(imgData, forPasteboardType: kUTTypePNG as String);
    pb.image = image;

Comment: Ok, are you familiar with UICollectionViewDelegate method 'didSelectItemAt indexPath' ? Please implement that method, it will get called once the particular cell (image) is tapped. Get your image from array of uiimages you're displaying. And then copy that image to UIPasteboard using the code in comment 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125575/discussion-between-ramakrishna-and-user3404693).